# How to update a column of a table with value of another column of another table snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having a table "sales" With columns tranid and date

| Tranid | trancode | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1100 | aa1 | null |
| 1101 | aa2 | null |

The next table is "order"

```
Tranid  orderid  orddate
1100    aa1      2022-06-01
1101    aa2      2022-06-02
1104    aa4      2022-06-09
```

Now I want to update the date column which is null with column date of order. So that the final results looks like this.

```
Tranid  trancode  date
 
1100    aa1      2022-06-01
1101    aa2      2022-06-02
```

This is by matching tranid with tranid and trancode with orderid values

I tried running the below statement

```
Update sales set date = o.orddate from order as o inner join sales as s on 
o.tranid = s.tranid and o.orderid = s.trancode
```

The table is getting updated but both the date values in sales table is getting updates 2022-06-01 it's not getting updated with respect to tranid and trancode. Any better way to code this?

Comment: Snowflake update command does not support join clause, For some other `DBMS`s like SQL Server your query will work as intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont need to rejoin with order. Its a simple update.

```
update sales s set date1=o.orddate
from orders o where s.tranid = o.tranid and s.trancode = o.orderid;
```

Table after update -

```
select * from sales;
```

| TRANID | TRANCODE | DATE1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1100 | aa1 | 2022-06-01 |
| 1101 | aa2 | 2022-06-02 |

Comment: Noted will check thanks bhai

Answer (score 1):

You can update this like:-

```
UPDATE sales SET date=(
SELECT orddate
FROM order
WHERE sales.Tranid = order.Tranid
);
```