# Coalesce gives repeat columns that prevents doing a union

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, union, coalesce

I have two tables (Table 1 and Table 2) that I join to then do a coalesce. So...

```
SELECT t1.*,
coalesce(t1.A, t2.A_T) as A
FROM table1 as t1
INNER JOIN table2 as t2 
 ON t1.key = t2.key
```

[image]

Doing what I said above, I will get a repeated A column given I want to replace missing values in **A** *from Table 1* with Table 2's **A** column. I want to do a union but a repeated A column is an issue (as seen in Table 3). You cannot do a union with different numbers of columns.

How can I fix this issue?

What I want:

[image]

Note: the actual tables I am working with have over 40 columns each. But this example is to get to the point of my issue.

Comment: Are there any keys to each of these tables that relate them together or are you relying on the rows being in order? Your request isn't making a lot of sense. I understand visually the output you want, however you need to be able to relate two tables together to be able to join then. Are just only related on row number?

Comment: Yeah so they are being related to each other by a number key. Key = number key.

Comment: If you run your SQL statement against the data you've provided in Table1/2 then the result is Table4 - which is what you are looking for. I'm not sure what the issue is?

Comment: I don't want a duplicate column but I want to keep the same name. Coalesce leads to a duplicate. Also I have more than the number of columns I show here. I have over 40 in eac table. Want to find an optimal way to not have to call ea. column by name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snowflake supports `exclude` so you could do

```
select coalesce(t1.A, t2.A_T) as A, t1.* exclude(t1.A)
from ...
```

Note that your problem stems from the fact that you are using `*` to select columns instead of being explicit about which columns to select.

Comment: I have way too many columns to list them.

Perhaps my solution is an update?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72718649/how-to-update-a-column-of-a-table-with-value-of-another-column-of-another-table

Comment: I'm thinking a union will not be possible this way?

Comment: My answer works well when the column you're trying to manipulate is either the first or last. If column A is somewhere else, it's probably better to store the result of your query to a temp table, set the old column to new column using an update, drop the new column using an alter, then do union as you wish